# Stepper motor turning only in one direction, stalling in opposite direction

Tags: stepper-motor

Components in use for project:
Arduino Mega --> [StepStick](http://reprap.org/wiki/StepStick) --> 28BYJ-48 5V Stepper

The stepper is 5V but I am using it at 8V since the A4988 driver requires a minimum motor voltage of 8V. It's a 5-wire unipolar motor, but I opened up the cover on it and cut the trace connecting the 2 coils, so it should be operating as a 4-wire bipolar stepper.

I am testing it with the [AccelStepper](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/) library for Arduino, running a program to make it turn one direction and then reverse every few seconds.

The issue: it turns fine in one direction, I can feel/hear/see it turning correctly, and then it simply stalls when it's supposed to turn in reverse. When attempting to reverse I can feel the pulsing/jerking of the motor coils seemingly out of step, while in the 'forward' direction it feels perfectly synchronized.

The driver is fine to the best of my knowledge, as I hooked up some LEDs to the stepper drive pins to check if the pulses were coming out alright, and they seem to be in sequence just fine. While keeping the LEDs plugged in, I reconnected the motor one wire at a time, and the pulses kept coming in order ... until I plugged in the fourth wire of the motor. Then, the pulses for the 'reverse' direction seemed to be stalled, while still coming out alright for the 'forward' direction. I reconnected the stepper wires in all possible configurations, and the only result was that the stepper then turned in reverse, but stalled on forward motion instead.

I have no idea what could be wrong, and I don't have easy access to more stepper motors or drivers.

EDIT: [here's the post](http://www.jangeox.be/2013/10/change-unipolar-28byj-48-to-bipolar.html) I'd seen about converting the stepper from unipolar to bipolar. I'm using the same motor.

MORE EDIT: I managed to scrounge an old regular bipolar stepper from a printer. Same problem. It has to be the driver. As long as the stepper is NOT connected to the output, the stepping signals come out fine. If I connect the wires one by one, the signals still come out fine. But, as soon as I plug in the 4th wire of the stepper, it goes haywire. HELP.

Comment: An unknown stepper motor with a modification done by yourself which, quite possibly is incorrect? Did it work before as a unipolar stepper?

Comment: @Andyaka: It's supposedly a popular small stepper, normally driven with 4 pins and a ULN2003 or something. I can't find the post where it said to cut the trace, or I'd have linked it here. It worked before, but tended to heat up somewhat. EDIT: found the post I'd seen.

Comment: Is your stepper a 28BYJ-48?

Comment: @Andyaka yes. Thought I had linked that in the question

Comment: Check your adafruit link - it doesn't appear to be that one but I may have not seen the reference correctly.

Comment: @Andyaka: Removed the adafruit link, the motor is the same as what I've linked in my edit